# Typescript props JSX.Element is not assignable to type ComponentType

Tags: typescript, sanity

I have a problem with type checking on renderDefault properties for my function object. url, string works as string but renderDefault keeps complaining. Created a type PreviewProps to assign the correct type.

```
import { PreviewProps, defineField, defineType } from 'sanity'
import getYouTubeId from 'get-youtube-id'
import LiteYouTubeEmbed from 'react-lite-youtube-embed'

import 'react-lite-youtube-embed/dist/LiteYouTubeEmbed.css'

const Preview = (props: PreviewProps & { url: string }) => {
  const { url, title = 'YouTube Embed', renderDefault } = props

  if (!url) {
    return <div>Missing YouTube URL</div>
  }

  const id = getYouTubeId(url)

  return (
    <div>
      {renderDefault({ ...props, title })}
      <LiteYouTubeEmbed title={title as string} id={id as string} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default defineType({
  name: 'youtube',
  type: 'object',
  title: 'YouTube Embed',
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: 'title',
      type: 'string',
      title: 'YouTube video title'
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'url',
      type: 'url',
      title: 'YouTube video URL'
    })
  ],
  preview: {
    select: {
      title: 'title',
      url: 'url'
    }
  },
  components: {
    preview: Preview
  }
})




Type '(props: PreviewProps & {    url: string;}) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<PreviewProps<PreviewLayoutKey>> | undefined'.
  Type '(props: PreviewProps & {    url: string;}) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<PreviewProps<PreviewLayoutKey>>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PreviewProps<PreviewLayoutKey>' is not assignable to type 'PreviewProps<PreviewLayoutKey> & { url: string; }'.
        Property 'url' is missing in type 'PreviewProps<PreviewLayoutKey>' but required in type '{ url: string; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message typically occurs in a TypeScript React application when [trying](https://mt-hunter1.com/) to pass a JSX.Element as a prop to a component that is expecting a ComponentType.

Answer (score 0):

you should `import {PreviewProps} from 'sanity';`, not use your own type. You are getting the error because those types are different

Comment: Updated my code stil getting errors: